Sveltekit + Socket.io + set-cookies
How do you guys set cookies in Sveltekit, if socket.io token is expired? Is it even possible?
The official approach with +page.server.ts won't work in this case for obvious reasons. But a scenario when page is opened without XHR calls for long time is possible.
